# Invariable day in date-input

Tags: html, validation, input

Is there any way to force date-inputs in HTML5 to require the first day of a month as being the only option ?
Assuming I use the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, the date "**01/12/2012**" will be allowed while "**02/12/2012**" will not be.

In other words, the user will be able to change the month or year but not the day which will be invariable at the value "**01**".

**Note**: I was able to do it with javascript, but frankly it seems overkill and will take a lot more work to provide a good user experience, I assume this is a thing that should/could be handled with patterns, but can't find anything on internet as it seems patterns in HTML input dates do not serve validation (only `min` and `max` attributes do that). Here's the JS code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("date_input");

var date = new Date(e.value);
var day = date.getDate();

if( day !== 1 ){
    var month = date.getMonth();
    if(month.length < 2) {
        month = "0"+month;
    }; 
    document.getElementById("date_input").value = date.getFullYear()+"-"+month+"-01";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function dateCheck(){
             var e = document.getElementById("inpDate");

             var date = new Date(e.value);
             var day = date.getDate();


             if(day!=1){
                        document.getElementById ("errDisplay").innerHTML="Wrong input. Please enter correct day (First day of the month)"; 
                        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Date Field Restrictions</h2>
  <h6> Enter a date: </h6>
  <input type="date" name="date" id="inpDate">
  <button type="button" onclick="dateCheck()">Try it</button>
  <p id="errDisplay"></p>

</body>
</html>
```